# Cardinality of the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the set of all sequences of 0s and 1s, in which no more than two identical characters are nearby, finite, countable or continuum?

My thoughts:

- Of course, it is not the finite.
- We can separate our sequence by `0` `1` `00` `11` and make bijection, in which `00` = `2` and `11` = `3`. So we got a set of quaternary notation symbols.
  Then we can say that it equipotent to $4^N$. But we have a limit that `0` and `2` or `1` and `3` can't be nearby, because in this case we will get `000` or `111` and that contradicts the hypothesis. So we can't make bijection from our sequence to all real numbers in quaternary notation (?) and our set less than a continuum (?).

Comment: Didn't you ask this already and received an answer from MJD?

Comment: Yes, I did, but didn't receive a good answer, because I didn't give a good task description.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question you should have edited it. This shows an incredible disrespect to the *free* work that MJD had put into his answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did wrong. I had no purpose to offend somebody.

Comment: I'm sure of that, but you should know for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use as your symbol dictionary the sequences $01$, $001$, $011$ and $0011$. All your sequences are composed by these symbols in any possible order, plus an optional prefix $1$ or $11$ (which wouldn't change the cardinality).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Am I right that now I can make bijection $0 = 01$, $1 = 001$, $2 = 011$, $3 = 0011$. And then can I prove that our sequence of $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ equipotent to real numbers set (quaternary notation). (How to do it strictly?)

Comment: Each sequences of ${0,1,2,3}$ correspond to the decimal expansion of some real number (not all of them), thus you get $<$. Then, each subset of $\mathbb{N}$ corresponds to its characteristic function ($\chi(S)_n = 1$ if $n\in S$, $\chi(S)_n = 0$ if $n\notin S$), so you get $>$.

Comment: Could you explain more about $>$? What cardinality we get in total?

Comment: You should already know that $card(\mathbb{R}) = card(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}))$. I have suggested above that $card(\{0,1,2,3\}^\mathbb{N}) < card(\mathbb{R})$ and that $card(\{0,1,2,3\}^\mathbb{N}) > card(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}))$.

Comment: Then $card({0,1,2,3}^N)<card(R)$ and $card({0,1,2,3}^N)>card(R)$. Couldn't use Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem, because there is no $≤$. What should I do now?